# Can we find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $f,g,h$ are strictely positive integers

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, diophantine-equations, fractions

Let $a>2$ and $b>2$ two strictely positive integers. Let us consider the following quantities:
$$ f= \dfrac{xy+ay+a^{2}}{by}$$
$$g=a(y+a)\dfrac{xy+ay+a^{2}}{by^{2}x}$$
$$h=\dfrac{y+a}{b}$$

My **question** is:

Can we find integers $x$ and $y$ (not necessarly positive) such that $f,g,h$ are strictely positive integers. Or at lest how one can proves that they are exist.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other restrictions? It's too easy. Let $b = x = y =1$ and all your expressions are positive integers.

Comment: @Tito: we could have $b > 1$ as $b$ is arbitrary

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: question edited.

Comment: @Ze2: If I use $b=2$ and $x\neq y$ it is still possible.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: the nice answer is when $x$ and $y$ depend mainly on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Note that $y = hb-a$, so you can choose $h$ to be whatever you want, if that helps.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar: It becomes the same problem.

Comment: @Ze2: If I find a formula for $b=3$, you will move $b$ up again?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: No. This is just a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let,

$$a = (bk-1)y,\quad x = by$$

then the three polynomials lose their denominators,

$$(bk^2-k+1)y,\quad (bk-1)(bk^2-k+1)ky,\quad ky$$

and are positive integers if $b,k,y$ are positive integers.

Comment: This doesn't work: what if $a = 3$ and $b = 10$? Then how do you find $k$ and $y$ positive integers making $a = (bk-1)y$?

Comment: @AshwinIyengar: The free parameters are $b,\,k,\,y$. Once chosen, they determine $a,x$.

Comment: The first thing that is written in the question is "let $a > 2$ and $b > 2$ be strictly positive integers", which, I would think, implies that $b$ isn't free.